# Does DynamoDB Secure Wipe the table after deletion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to make sure that DynamoDB "Secure Wipes" a table after it has been deleted from the database. I am looking for references in the AWS Documentation where this is mentioned. This feature is needed for security compliance. Can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: Compliance with what framework?

Comment: My Company is trying to get a SOC2 Compliance Certification. One of the requirements is to show how securely we handle customer Data. As part of off-boarding a customer we need to securely delete their data from our system.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, DynamoDB delete operations are "Secure Deletes" by default. Should you have PITR enabled, when you delete a table it will create a backup of that data for you. So you would also have to delete that backup and any other you may have stored.

Comment: Can I get a link to AWS Documentation where this is mentioned. I need to add the reference as an evidence to my security documentation. We are undergoing a security audit to obtain a SOC2 certification.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/artifact/getting-started/